# Will Reset of Windows 10 on Surface Pro 3 get back to 8.1 (original was Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I have a need to reset Windows 10 on SP3. SP3 originally came with Windows 8.1 installed, but then was upgraded to Windows 10 via free windows upgrade when 10 was released. There are two options to reset the SP3 from Control Panel:

1. Remove everything
2. Restore factory settings

Question is: if I go with the second one, will I still have Win10 or it would go back to 8.1? I really don't want to go back to 8.1 so if anyone knows for sure I really appreciate any advice. Couldn't get definite answer by googling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question, if your system reserved partition still exists, and you execute the operation restore factory settings, your machine will go back to Windows 8.1(its original system) rather than Windows 10. But don’t worry, it can also upgrade to windows 10.
If you want to reset Windows 10, please refer to this link below for some assistance.

[Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

In general, we usually choose system restore to recover a previous healthy state, it’s up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assume you're right, and I went with option 1 so I don't need to upgrade to 10 again.